# Minimizing the time needed to reach at a point with constraints

Tags: calculus, classical-mechanics

Consider a situation of particle located at origin and velocity of $V_°$ along y-axis .  . The maximum possible acceleration magnitude which can be attained by that particle is $a_°$ for any moment of time . Now if the particle wants to reach a point $(d,0)$ in shortest possible time , what shape of the trajectory needs to be so as to make that possible ?

> My progress : i let the acceleration along x -axis to be $a_x(t)$ and along y-axis to be $a_y(t)$ now $V_°- \int_{0}^{t}a_y(t)dt = v_y$ ..(i) , $\int_{0}^{t}a_x(t)dt =v_x$ ..(ii) and $\sqrt(a_y(t)^2 + a_x(t)^2)$ = $a_°$..(iii) . Now to minimize time i think we need to maximize the average velocity along x -axis during the whole motion . But how do we so i am stuck now as such i think my problem is variables are more and i have less equations .

- Note : Answer is Parabolic trajectory if someone wanted to know .

Comment: You can reach any point in the plane with any positive acceleration limit.  As an existence proof, decelerate along $y$ until you stop, then accelerate towards the destination.  There are faster ways.

Comment: Nice point thanks and for the optimal time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the situation in the inertial frame of reference where you're initially at the origin with zero velocity. (Note that the acceleration constraint is the same in this moving frame.)  The destination point is initially at $(d,0)$, and after time $t$ it will be at $(d,-V_0 t)$.  On the other hand, the farthest you can get from the origin in time $t$ is $\frac{1}{2}a_0 t^2$, achievable through maximum acceleration in any fixed direction.  So the minimum time is just the minimum positive solution to $\frac{1}{2}a_0t^2=\sqrt{d^2 + V_0^2 t^2}$.  Squaring both sides, this becomes a quadratic in $t^2$: $\frac{1}{4}a_0^2 t^4 - V_0^2 t^2 - d^2 = 0$, with solutions
$$
t^2 = \frac{V_0^2 \pm \sqrt{V_0^4 + a_0^2 d^2}}{a_0^2/2}.
$$
If $d\neq 0$, then only the $+$ sign leads to a solution for $t$:
$$
t^{*}=\sqrt{2\left(\frac{V_0}{a_0}\right)^2 + 2\sqrt{\left(\frac{V_0}{a_0}\right)^4 +  \left(\frac{d}{a_0}\right)^2}} = \sqrt{2\alpha^2+2\sqrt{\alpha^4 + \beta^4}}=2\alpha\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1 + (\beta/\alpha)^4}}
$$
where $\alpha=V_0/a_0$ and $\beta=\sqrt{d/a_0}$ are the two parameters in the problem with dimensions of time.  And, of course, constant acceleration leads you along a parabolic trajectory in the original frame.

Comment: Can you once also give a argument on how we can cross out the possibility of the path to be a curve in that frame? I can get intuitevely about straight path but how to rigourous arugmemt wise rule out the possibility of curve for meeting of sttaight line and a curve ?

Comment: Just write the equations of motion in polar coordinates.  You'll find an upper bound on the second derivative of $r(t)$, which will lead to the desired upper bound on $r(t)$ itself... $r(t) \le (1/2)a_0 t^2$.

Answer (score 0):

I can't prove it optimal, but it won't be far wrong to use a constant acceleration.  Compute the time from your starting conditions to $y=0$ as a function of $a_y$ and the time to $x=d$ as a function of $a_x$.  Set those equal and solve the pair simultaneously with $\sqrt{a_x^2+a_y^2}=a$.  You may have to do it numerically.  Let $\theta$ be the angle of the acceleration vector and use a root finder.

Comment: Actually this is the optimal case , but i dont know how to show it yet but thanks though for insights

Comment: Does making velocity space graph helps to prove it ? It might be a nice way

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: Accelaration vector is constant.

Under the assumption above, $\vec{a}=<a_x,-a_y> $ and so we take $a_x^2+a_y^2=a_0^2$ for minumum time. Then, the following equations must be satisfied:

1. $\frac{1}{2}a_xt_{min}^2=d$
2. $-\frac{1}{2}a_yt_{min}^2+v_0t_{min}=0$

If we solve the equations, since $x=x(t)=\frac{1}{2}a_xt^2$ and $y=y(t)=-\frac{1}{2}a_yt^2+v_0t$, we find the parabola
$$y=-\frac{\sqrt{a_0^2-a_x^2}}{a_x}x+\frac{\sqrt{2}v_0}{\sqrt{a_x}}\sqrt{x}
\;\;\;\text{where}\;\;\; a_x=\frac{\sqrt{v_0^4+d^2a_0^2}-v_0^2}{d}.$$
But, I can't imagine a solution without the assumption. It must involve high level of calculus of variations.

Comment: You may share how to start with the calculus of variation method ? I think i may try fully proving it ?

Comment: I don't know...

Comment: $x''(t)^2+y''(t)^2=a_0^2$... @ProblemDestroyer